# android show dot character in StaticLayout

Tags: android, ascii

I would like to show a dot character "\u2022"
in a StaticLayout inside a custom view,
how it can be done?

```
TextPaint paint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
CharSequence text = "test \\u2022 test";
int textWidth = paint.measureText(text, 0, text.length());
StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, paint, (int) textWidth, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1f, 0f, true);
```

Comment: what you mean by "set"? your `text` variable contains that unicode character, so?

Comment: ok so you mean "test \u2022 test" ? not "test \\u2022 test"

Comment: I want to show a dot in the staticLayout....but it shows the ascii, how its possible to show the dot char? (its encoding is \\u2022)